# Hypothesis testing for increase in sales

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test

A company is planning to setup the option for self checkout (SCO) in all of its stores.

As a trial, they are looking to estimate the benefits of SCO in terms of increase in transaction volume by installing in  only 1 or 2 stores first and collecting data for a period of n months (n <5 ) from it.

The claim is that it would increase transaction volume by 1% per month (12.68% annual)

My aim to test this claim and estimate whether SCO does help increase the transaction volume.

Observing past data of transaction volume at the stores where trial is planned, I notice the following :

- Looking at previous year data, I observe that transaction volume in the stores varies significantly from one month to another. If I look at % change over previous month , it can go like +20%, -40%, +60% and so on.
- Given such variation, it's not possible to directly test whether there's been a 1% monthly increase due to SCO or not in just n months
- Transactions tend to increase in those months where it's a major holiday in the country and towards in year end in December.
- Going from one year to another, the stores are likely to grow in terms of transaction volume - External factors like the economy would affect it from one year to another.

I don't think using paired t-test would be appropriate given the seasonal variation and other external factors affecting sales.

Considering these points I am thinking of the following approach :

Null hypothesis : There is no significant difference in transaction volume

Alternative : Transaction volume has increased

Alpha level : 10%

- Pick two stores which are as similar to each other as possible in terms of transaction volume, proximity, sales etc.
- Take one as control and other one as experimental. The experimental will have SCO installed in it.
- Look at the historical distribution of difference between transaction volume between control and experimental store (or simulate a distribution based on FY21 mean and standard deviation?)
- Collect the data for n months after SCO is installed and calculate the difference between transaction volume of control and experimental. Difference would (almost) remove the affect of common external factors.
- Check whether the p-value is less than alpha. If it's less, reject null.

Need your thoughts on this approach and other alternative ways in which can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a satisfactory control and experiment group, you could use the "**Difference in differences**" approach. But you have to ascertain whether the stores you are comparing are in fact similar. The differences could be due to other factors as well.

You could look into the "**Segmented Regression of Interrupted Time Series**" approach.

Your regression under this approach will be:

Transaction volume = a + B1(time) + B2(SCO) + B3(time after SCO) + e

where,

The "time" variable represents the time period of observation. It accounts for any trend in the data.

The "SCO" variable takes the value of "0" before SCO is introduced and "1" after SCO is introduced. It will account for the immediate effect on the dependent variable.

The "time after SCO" variable represents the time periods after the intervention. It will count the time periods after SCO is introduced. It will show how the effects of SCO evolve over time.

For this to work well, the trend in your data must be linear. This is the basic idea and layout, you can add any control variables that you need.